# How do i set the dns search suffix for a network adapter in .net?

Tags: c#, .net, networking, wmi

I've written a command line utility that detects which network interface is connected, and sets the staitc ip address and dns servers for it (by calling netsh). However, I can't seem to figure out how to set the dns search suffixes. netsh doesnt appear capable of doing that. How do I do that otherwise  (WMI perhaps)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have to set the value(s) you want in the DNSDomainSuffixSearchOrder property of the Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration WMI object.

Here's and example of setting values in WMI, if you need it:
[Modifying Objects & Running Methods](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/5450/using-wmi-from-managed-code/3/)

Answer (score 0):

The dns search suffixes are valid for the whole machine, not for a single network adapter. You can also get them from registry:

```
string searchList = "";
try 
{
    using (var reg = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(tcpSettingsSubKey))
    {
        searchList = (reg.GetValue("SearchList") as string);
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    // something went wrong
}
```

(This is not the default dns suffix when the machine is an AD member)